# Mongoid model with hardcoded data

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid, rack

I have a mongoid model

```
class MyMongoidModel
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :name, :type => String
  field :data_id, :type => Integer

  has_and_belongs_to_many :the_other_model, :class_name => 'class_name_model'
  has_many :model2

  def self.all
        [  
               #.... the hardcoded data that will never be changed
        ]
  end
end
```

it's used by the other model and it uses them as well. However, it contains the data that **won't be changed** for a very long time, let's say, at all. Thus, I don't want to retrieve it from db, I want it to be hardcoded and, at the same time, I want it **acts** like a normal mongoid model. Using caching is not what I'm looking for.

I hope you understand what I mean.

How do accomplish it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a great gem called active_hash that provides this functionality for ActiveRecord: defining a fixed set of data as models you can reference/relate to normal models, but have it defined in code and loaded in memory (not stored/retrieved from DB).

https://github.com/zilkey/active_hash

Interestingly, since Mongoid and ActiveRecord both share common ActiveModel basis, you may be able to use active_hash with a Mongoid document now.

For example:

```
class Country < ActiveHash::Base
  self.data = [
    {:id => 1, :name => "US"},
    {:id => 2, :name => "Canada"}
  ]
end

class Order
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  has_one :country
end
```